# How to capture audio in Sencha Touch (Cordova)?

Tags: sencha-touch, audio-recording

I am packaging Sencha Touch application with Cordova.

I have found that usual  HTML element doesn't work with Sencha Touch.
How to capture from mic. using Sencha Touch packaged with Cordova? Sencha Touch has Ext.Audio component but all demos are about playback, not recording. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch is only about UI and data, you can't access the phone's hardware with it (only HTML5/javascript). In order to record audio, you'll need to use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

It's another javascript framework using Sencha and that convert javascript into native code, allowing the developer to access the phone's hardware.
For recording audio :

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html

Comment: May I do the same but package with Cordova only?